# Git: clone on mac, view in windows (through parallels)

Tags: windows, macos, git, parallels

I have a Mac with Parallels installed running Windows 7. I'm doing development on both OS's, though mostly on Windows 7.

I've set it up so that I'm working on a directory in OS X that Windows can see and work on because it sees the host disk as local drive Z:\

Because I've dedicated fewer resources to Windows in Parallels, it's not as fast at cloning repositories as the Mac is. However, when I clone the repository on the Mac, and then look at it in Windows, `git status` shows *a lot* of changes.

I did some Googling and found that setting core.autocrlf to true helps with some of the issues, and core.filemode is supposed to ignore the filemode, but it doesn't look like it's working. Now, in gitk, all of the changes are like this:

```
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

Despite the fact that ls -l on the file in question returns the same permissioning.

Also, it appears that for some symbolic links in the repo, the Mac is making .lnk files, which Windows now reports as untracked files.

The issues seem to mostly go away if I clone from Windows, but the clone within the parallels install is way slower than it is on the Mac.

Does anyone have advice for how to deal with the file mode issue and the .lnk issue, or some other general advice for using git across both windows and os x via parallels?

Comment: Is it acceptable to use a remote bare repository (say, Bitbucket)? This will also be a backup measure, since both repos are technically on one machine and disk, so they are vulnerable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm already working from a remote repository (and no, I can't change what the remote one is using), so there's no vulnerability issue.

Comment: How was this resolved?